# CSS Title with an horizontal line in the middle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a horizontal rule with some text in the left.

for example:

my title -------------------------------------

I can do it by putting a background to the text but without the colored background, I can not

Is anybody has an answer ?

```
<style>   
h1 {
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:0;
    height:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;   
    vertical-align:middle;

}
</style>
<h1><span>my title</span></h1>
```

Thanks

Comment: is `------------------` supposed to be text or an image?

Comment: If the answsers below do not solve your issue, could you please clarify the result that you're looking for, and why certain scenarios won't work?

Answer (score 4):

Your suggestion of putting a background color on the span seems to work reasonably well.  [See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/aGEZx/)

Alternately, you could use a background image in place of the border on the `h1`.

```
h1 { background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nomLz.gif) repeat-x left center; }

h1 span {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding-right: 3px;
}
```

[Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ef72D/)

(A 1x1 black image for the background.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nomLz.gif))

Comment: I'd suggest using the background color on the span, to be honest - doesn't require the use of an extra image (although the image could be customizable, if that's what was needed). +1 for versatility.

Comment: Agreed.  I wasn't precisely sure of the desired outcome, so I provided another option.

Answer (score 1):

without using the background you could try with:

```
<style>   

span:after{
    content:"-------------------------------------";
}
</style>
<h1><span>my title</span></h1>
```

In this case you are using the CSS :after pseudo class.
Have a look to [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter_content.html) to check cross-browser compatibility.
And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uR7Gw/) you will find a pre-coded example.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The positive aspect of this solution is that it works with ANY background color.
And the drawback is crossbrowser compat